# Azure portal's active directory app integration with power bi content

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded, azureportal

I have created an native app enabling powerbi service permissions in azure portal going through azure active directory -> app registration. Now I want to create power bi reports, workspace on that created app but if I go to https://app.powerbi.com I can't see that created app on my power bi app.

I am confused here actually how to add power bi reports under that app because I want to access power bi rest api using adal.js lib where I need app id and want to access reports under that app.

Anybody can clear my confusion here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your confusion is with the terms "[Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/service-create-distribute-apps)" in Power BI. The app you registered has nothing in common with these. It is a guid, used from Power BI to identify your native app.

When you create a native app, you register it (what you did) and Power BI REST API uses this appID (also called ClientID) to identify your app and the permissions it has. When you call the API, you need an access token. It will be acquired in the context of some user. This user must have rights for the reports you want to access. So simply make a workspace, grant rights to users and publish your reports there. Then you will be able to embed them in your app.

Comment: I am trying to access one of the power bi rest api here: https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/reports/xxxxxxx  but I am getting bad request with status: 400, what could be the reason ?

Comment: Read the error message returned in the response stream. It should give you more information.

Comment: I am using adal.js but when I request using this url https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/reports getting 200 ok, strange

Comment: I can't see any response is blank in my chrome network tab. I am requesting this api from my localhost, is this could be the reason of happening 400 error?

Comment: I could not know what you do. I can see your code. Enter new question showing your code and giving detailed information about the error you get and your problem in general.

Comment: thanks for your help, here is my new post if you can help so that I can accept your answer there also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53669971/200-ok-response-from-power-bi-rest-api-but-no-json